# Telethon error when import InputPeerChannel

Tags: python, telethon

I just started learning python. Now I'm doing a bot for Telegram. To work with the Core API, I use the Telethon library for Python 3. The error occurs in the line:

```
from telethon.utils import InputPeerChannel
```

Error text:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Work\Projects\Python\Bots\NewsBot\main.py", line 5, in <module>
    from telethon.utils import InputPeerChannel
ImportError: cannot import name 'InputPeerChannel' from 'telethon.utils' (F:\Work\Projects\Python\Bots\NewsBot\venv\lib\site-packages\telethon\utils.py)
```

- Version Telethon 1.24.0
- Python 3.9
- IDE PyCharm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `ImportError` in python indicates that the name (`InputPeerChannel` in this case) isn't in the module (`telethon.utils` in this case) or that the module can't be found.

In your case happens the first, the module `telethon.utils` exists but it not contains the name `InputPeerChannel`. This name can be found in the module `tlethon.tl.types` so you can import it from there.

```py
>>> from telethon.tl.types import InputPeerChannel
```